# rsyslog TLS on AIX

Tags: tls, rsyslog, aix, gnutls, elk

I am trying to forward logs with `rsyslog (8.4.2)` on `AIX 7.1` and I need to encrypt with TLS. However it seems I need `rsyslog-gnutls` package. I can't seem to find this package anywhere for AIX. Best I could find is http://www.oss4aix.org/download/RPMS/rsyslog/ and that is for rsyslog version 5. I really don't want to downgrade. Can anyone point me to where I can get this installed? Or any alternative solutions.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can find the link to the download you are looking for here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1019934

You will need to create a IBM ID if you don't have one already to login. I logged in and the version you are looking for is available (V 8.4.2.0).

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I am looking for the rsyslog-gnutls. I have rsyslog. I need rsyslog-gnutls, because that is required for rsyslog TLS encryption.

Comment: Perhaps this then?  

http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Gnutls

Answer (score -1):

There are several alternative options if you require encryption, Filebeat and fleuntd are two that come to mind. Both do the job quite well and are easily installed.

Comment: Filebeat runs on Go. Go is not compatible on AIX. Fluentd should work since its written in Ruby, but I am not for sure.